# Pygame side scroller arcade

Tags: python, pygame

im writing a side scrolling arcade game where you control a rocket and you have to avoid asteroids. The last part where I want to have the asteroids move accros the screen from right to left does not work out yet. This is the code I have so far, but when I run this nothing happens. I also tried it a bit different and then all the asteroids appeared at the same time. Help is very much appreciated.

```
import pygame as pg
from random import *



pg.init()

asteroidgif = pg.image.load("Asteroid.gif")
asteroidimg = pg.transform.scale(asteroidgif, (75,75))

#Setup screen and define colors
res = (1000,800)
screen = pg.display.set_mode(res)
pg.display.set_caption('Rocket game')

#pg.image.load("space.jpg")
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
background1 = pg.image.load("space.jpg").convert()
background2 = pg.image.load("space.jpg").convert()


#Generate random asteroids.
Nasteroid = 1
i = 0
x = 999
y = randint(1,800)
dx = 10                 #pixel step for asteroid
dy = 0
while i < Nasteroid:
    x = x - dx
    y = y

    pg.event.pump()
    screen.blit(asteroidimg,(x,y))
    pg.display.flip()
    i = i + 1
pg.quit()
```

Comment: What did you adjust when you 'tried it a bit different'? Also how exactly is it not working, that no asteroids are appearing?

Comment: I used other code I already deleted, and yes indeed the asteroids are not appearing at all while I do seem to blit them on the screen. Im fairly new to python and pygame

Comment: Even if it's deleted, could you explain what you were trying to change and why? It could be quite helpful for resolving your problem.

Comment: I had the part where i generate the asteroids inside my game loop. The asteroids appeared on the right side of my screen and kept on generating but remained at the right of my screen. I want them not to appear at the same time and move them across the screen like a "highway of asteroids" instead of cars.

Comment: Why are you moving them inside a while loop that only runs once? (`while i < Nasteroid: ... i = i + 1`) You set Nasteroid as 1 a little above that, and `i=0`

Comment: It was an attempt to generate the asteroids one by one, blit them on the screen and then generate the next one.

Answer (score 2):

Projects using Pygame require an explicit "mainloop" of the game -
a part of your code that will run again and again for each frame
(or even more often) of your application.

And - for moving all asteroids, you need to loop over all 
asteroids, in each frame.

In your learning stage, you have confused the need for the two distinct loops - so what should be your "eternal" mainloop is exiting as soon as you interate over all asteroids:

```
while i < Nasteroid:
    x = x - dx
    y = y
    ...
    pg.display.flip()
    i = i + 1
pg.quit()
```

see above? ater your first pass i cotains "2", and your loop is exited.
As a first step, before your game becomes actually interactive you will need at least:

```
while True:
    i = 0
    pg.event.pump()
    while i < Nasteroid:
        x -= dx
        #y = y
        screen.blit(asteroidimg,(x,y))
        i = i + 1
    pg.display.flip()
    pg.time.delay(30)
pg.quit()
```

This should suffice fr you to see a single asteroid to dart on your screen once, before the application exits - tehre are several more steps before getting this to playable, but you should approach one thing at a time. As one next thing that won't work:  you can obviously use global "x" and "y" variables for more than one asteroid - the basic approach is to have all your asterois in a  container -like a Python list, or a pygame sprite group, and to have each asteroid to hold its own coordinates.

Comment: Wow! Thank you, this indeed showed some improvement. What happens now (I added some of my own code) that an asteroid moves from right to left. However, the previous position of the asteroid still appears on the screen. How would I avoid this? Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: As I've said, there is a long way to go, and you have a lot to learn  with this project - however, since the specific issue you asked is resolved, I'd suggest you to ask other, new questions, with the newer versions of your code.